# iOS - UIScrollView doesn't update its content and some UIViews disappear after reload

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have `UITableViewController` with `UIScrollView` inside `UIView` as its header. 
`UIScrollView` is used to display slideshow of images:

```
UITableView
 -UITableViewHeaderView
   -UIView
      -UIScrollView
        -UIImageView
          ...
      -UIPageControl
```

Every image has a subview with its title and description:

```
UIImageView
  -UIView
    -UILabel
    -UILabel
```

When I need to update my `tableView` a delegate method is called which reloads data in a `tableView` and calls `addImages` method:

```
- (void)eventsUpdated
{
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setRefreshControl:)])
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self addImages];
}
```

Here is how I add my images:

```
- (void)addImages
[self.scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * i;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;

        UIImageView *subview = [self createImageViewForEvent:[images objectAtIndex:i] inFrame:frame];
        subview.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:subview];
    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*images.count, scrollView.frame.size.height);
    pageControll.currentPage = 0;
    pageControll.numberOfPages = images.count;

}

- (UIImageView *)createImageViewForEvent:(Event *)event inFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIImage *image;

    NSString *imageName = [event.imageName lastPathComponent];
    NSString *bundleFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[imageName stringByDeletingPathExtension] ofType:[imageName pathExtension]];

    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:bundleFilePath];


    UIImageView *output = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    output.frame = frame;

    UIView *descriptionView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, frame.size.height*0.7, frame.size.width, frame.size.height*0.3)];

    descriptionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5];
    descriptionView.alpha = 1.0;

    UILabel *header = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, frame.size.width-20, 12)];
    header.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:210/256.0 green:217/256.0 blue:231/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    header.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17];
    header.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    header.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    header.numberOfLines = 1;

    UILabel *description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 22, frame.size.width-20, 28)];
    description.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/256.0 green:255/256.0 blue:255/256.0 alpha:1.0];
    description.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
    description.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    description.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    description.numberOfLines = 2;

    header.text = event.title;
    [descriptionView addSubview:header];

    description.text = event.shortDesription;
    [descriptionView addSubview:description];

    [output addSubview:descriptionView];

    return output;
}
```

After first launch everything works fine, but if I try to reload my `tableView` and call `addImages` again, all UILabels disappear, only `UIImageView` and `UIView` are visible.

**UPD:**

What I have noticed, is that my UILabels appear after some time, approximately after 30 seconds. I have never experienced something similar before

**UPD 2:**

After I reload my `tableView` and `scrollview`, `scrollView's` content is not updated right away, only after I start scrolling

Comment: Is your `frame` the wrong size second time around?

Comment: If `frame.size` was 0 in either dimension then the labels would disappear, and it's not entirely clear what `frame.size` will be. I'd check that with an NSLog. But I'm just guessing because I don't see anything else obvious!

Comment: No, it is not zero. One of the subviews is still visible (output), but all its subviews are not displayed

Comment: Yes, I did. my scrollView property is (strong, nonatomic)

Comment: @Oleg Are you calling `addImages` on the main thread?

Comment: Have yo tried inverting the order of these calls: `[self.tableView reloadData];` and `[self addImages];`?  It could be the reloadData code delaying visual updates until an asynchronous call completes (unlikely, but oh well...).

Comment: Yes, I tried. I even put few "reloadData's" in a row, the same result. And also my scrollView is not being updated (redrawn) before I start scrolling

Comment: Another idea to try and rule out possibilities: have you tried moving the scrollview outside and above of the table view?  That would help us rule out it's a problem with the UITableView interfering with the UIScrollView updates.

Comment: Will try that tomorrow, its night in Norway already :-)

Comment: And yet another test you can perform: try commenting out `[self.table reloadData];` to see if the table reload is causing trouble.

Comment: Tried to comment reloadData - still the same, so maybe it is not a UITableView causing this problem

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20274/discussion-between-diegoreymendez-and-oleg)

Comment: UIImageView acts funky with subviews. Try to Add the UIImageView and the UILabel to a single UIView. So instead of UIImageView --> UIView --> UILabel try: UIView --> UIImageView, UILabel. Notice that the UILabel is NOT a subview of UIImageView.

Comment: Yes, tried that one as well. Wherever I put my UILabel they disappear and then appear again after some time. Tried hundreds of other things, looks like nothing helps

Comment: Could you add the method that calls `-eventsUpdated`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reproduced a sample project from the code you posted, and didn't find any refreshing issues on the labels nor on any other component.  This leads me to think the problem is not in the code you posted, but rather somewhere else.

Usually when you see such a delay, it is because some code that should not be running in parallel, is running in parallel.

I would suggest you check how and when you perform your call to `eventsUpdated`.  You must make sure that call is performed on the main thread, and only once your array of events has finished updating.  To check that, you can add add the following line in `eventsUpdated`:

`NSLog(@"Current: %@, main: %@", [NSThread currentThread], [NSThread mainThread]);`

Please post the log! :-)

I would suggest you also add to your question the code from the method that calls `eventsUpdated`, as it could also be of help.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Somehow my delegate methods were called on background thread, after I forced addImages to be performed on mainThread everything went to its place :-) Thank you for making me double check everything once again! You get my hardly-earned 50 points :-)

Comment: Good answer, I spent the last few hours trying to track down why my labels were appearing and disappearing and never even thought it could have been the threading optimisation I had added. Even though I was adding the view to a scrollview on the main thread, the labels that I had added on a background thread to the view would not appear immediately

Answer (score 0):

At first, never do something like

```
 [scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Scroll view has some internal views (scroll indicators, for example), so you're removing them which may dealloc them and cause strange crashes any time later.

As for your problem - try calling bringSubviewToFront: of your UIImageView to get your labels infront of everything else